# Getting an error in libxml library in ios

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am working on chat application in iOS. When i integrate XMPP framework in my app, i am getting an error in libxml library. can you please help me out? Please see the following screenshot.

Comment: The error is "expected ')' "in valid.h and parser.h files in libxml library in iOS. Sorry am not able to post the screenshot.

Comment: XMLPUBFUN xmlAttrPtr XMLCALL
 xmlGetID(xmlDocPtr doc,const xmlChar *ID);     expected ')'

Comment: Quit xcode remove derived data and reopen xcode

Comment: I did just now but getting the same error again

Comment: romive libxml.a and add it again

Comment: check library search path .You need to add livxml path there

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step

1. Add `Security.frameWork`,`coreGraphics.frameWork`,`foundation.fraework`,`uiKit .framework` ,`libxml2.tbd`,`cfnetwork.frameWork` ,`libresolv.tbd`, `CoreData.frameWork`, `systemConfig
   .frameWork` , `CoreLocation.frameWork` in Linked Frameworks and libraries
2. Set `Always search user paths` to `Yes`and  `User Header Search Paths : $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` make it `recursive`
3. Add in `Header Search Paths : $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` make it `non-recursive`
4. search `Other Linker Flags` and the add: `-lxml2`.
5. Now clean project and build for IPA
   [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntlbN.png)